# switching from client to server side javascript (due to vulnerability like disabling js in browser)

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha3.js"></script>
<script>
        var hash = '';
        var pass = '';
        while (hash != "0806b77a85f17c341cd62615ef320cbd5ada") { //dummy
                pass = prompt("Pass:", "");  //enter from client
                hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(pass); //#3
        };
</script>
```

I need to reprogram the above code to server side js - would that make it immune of disabling js in browser?

Comment: Yes, but it'd also make it pretty hard

Comment: what do you mean by server side JS ? what are you using for server-side? The question does not have enough information.

Comment: You either need to do it in something like php. node.js to keep javascript

Comment: You can't avoid browser JS entirely. User interaction has to be done in the browser-side. Then use AJAX to send input to the server-side script.

Comment: Unless you can do everything using forms and/or clicking on links.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling JS on the browser only means that every calculation must be done server-side.

If you want to keep using Javascript, then you should use [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/). CryptoJS has no problem running on it, so I believe the main logic of your code would be unchanged.

Also, if this is a password authentication, bear in mind that this must be sent using a HTTPS connection, so that it's not vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.